# Where can I find a list of functions, specifically views, that can be translated to a C standalone executable?

Tags: front-end, export, display

I want to create a standalone mathematica executable. I would like to have some view capabilities like CreateDialog or TabView or those kinds of things. I would like my users to have an interface to input dynamic strings and variables.

I want to do something like this:

```
function = TabView[{
   "General" -> Column[{
      Row[{TextCell["Project Name:"], InputField[Dynamic[proj]]}],
      Row[{TextCell["Number of Inputs:"], InputField[Dynamic[num]]}]
      }],
   "Another Tab" -> Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}]
   }, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Anyone familiar with this process?

Comment: It can't be done in a standalone executable. The presentation of these expressions is the responsibility of the front end, so you either have to write your own interface or use the [CDF player](http://www.wolfram.com/products/player/), which (I think) includes the normal FE.

Comment: I have often wished for this too! The ability to export mathematica dynamic gui code into html5 would be awesome.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A link was posted in comments that gives the [full list of compilable functions in Mathematica 8](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions). If you look at this list, you'll see in particular that there are no `*View`, no `*Dialog` and no `Input*` functions in this list. No user interface element can be compiled to C code or standalone executable in Mathematica.

The reason for this is straightforward: all user interface depends on the Mathematica front-end, i.e. the application you see running. Standalone applications don't link to the Mathematica front-end, so they can't include UI. In fact, if they did link to the Mathematica front-end, they would not be standalone executables anymore, because you would need to redistribute the front-end in some way along with the executable. Fortunately, there is another way to do this, through the use of the [CDF player](http://www.wolfram.com/products/player/) which allows you to create full-fledge Mathematica notebooks (including user interface) that will run on computers without the full Mathematica installation. Another possibility is to link you compiled Mathematica code with OS-specific UI  functions using the OS native UI elements (or a cross-platform toolkit, like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/), [Gtk](http://www.gtk.org/), [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org), …).

Comment: Thanks so much. This was very helpful. :)